# Python 2.7: Removing tuples from a list by value basis more than one condition

Tags: python, tuples

Suppose I have a list in the following format:

```
    [(99.0,0.14),(101.0,0.11),(104.0,4.5),(78.0,14.0)]
```

I want to iterate over the list of float values, check whether the value in the first index of the tuple is greater than 100 and whether the value in the second index of the tuple is greater than 10 and if either of the above conditions are true subsequently remove the tuple from the list entirely.

In order to get something like this:

```
    [(99.0,0.14)]
```

I tried this from @StefanPochmann's answer to the previous version of this question:

```
    z = [t for t in z if t[0] <= 100 and t[1] <= 10]
```

But it returns this error since I am dealing with float values within the tuples of the list:

```
   TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

What is the best way to perform this check?

Comment: To be clear, this is a `list` of `tuple`s, not a `tuple` of "items". The parenthesized pairs are each two element (immutable) `tuple`s, the brackets around the lot of them make a (mutable) `list`.

Comment: That code you show there isn't mine, and mine doesn't produce that error. And good job [changing the question, making correct answers look wrong.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/306960/1672429) Sigh.

Comment: The list comprehension you show, should work. That error would seem to mean either `z` is a `float`, or an element of `z` is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The max and min calls don't do anything: you're working with only one value at a time.  Get rid of those.

```
    z = [t for t in z if t[0] <= 100 and t[1] <= 10]
```

Answer (score 5):

List comprehension, keep the good tuples.

```
>>> tuples = [(99,78),(101,46),(104,69),(0,32)]
>>> [t for t in tuples if max(t) <= 100]
[(99, 78), (0, 32)]
```

It's btw not a tuple but a list.

Edit: This is an answer to the original question, not the current answer-invalidating changed one.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the solution above:

```
lt =  [(99,78),(101,46),(104,69),(0,32)]

# additional function which checks whether the tuple 
# contains elements greater than 100
all_less100 = lambda y: not bool(list(filter(lambda x: x > 100, y)))

# filter tuples that contains elements greater than 100
lt_filtered = list(filter(all_less100, lt))

print(lt_filtered)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    lt =  [(99,78),(101,46),(104,69),(0,32)]

    lt = filter(lambda x: x[0] < 100,lt)

    print(list(lt))

    [(99, 78), (0, 32)]

    or with list comprehension 

    lt = [ (x,y) for x,y in lt if x < 100]

    print(lt)

    [(99, 78), (0, 32)]
```

Comment: This only uses one of the two tests.